# How to create a dynamic dropdown based on other dropdowns?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a dashboard with four dropdowns. I'm trying to select the model based on the dropdowns. I have two drop downs, `market` and `submarket` but in some cases I need an additional dropdown (`model_selector` column) to appear if there is more than one model for the `market`-`submarket` combination to select the model.

E.g., the combination (MarketA, SubmarketX) has three models available: ModelA1, ModelA2, and ModelA3. In this case, a new dropdown `model_selector` should appear with values 1,2,3 so that we can select the final model.

I want the dropdowns to be in the same row, i.e. when a new dropdown appears, others should adjust the size to accommodate the new dropdown.
How can I do this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(data.table)


market <- c("MarketA", "MarketB", "MarketC", "MarketA","MarketA")
submarket <- c("SubmarketX", "SubmarketY", "SubmarketZ", "SubmarketX","SubmarketX")
models <- c("modelA1", "modelB1", "modelC1", "modelA2","modelA3")
model_selector <- c("1","1","1","2","3")

# Create data table
mod.selection <- data.table(
  market_name = market,
  submarket_name = submarket,
  model_name=models,
  model_selector=model_selector
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(Feature = character(0), Value = numeric(0)))
  observeEvent(input$select_market, {
    submarkets <- mod.selection$submarket_name[which(mod.selection$market_name == input$select_market)]
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_submarket", choices = submarkets, selected = submarkets[1])
  })
}

#Ui function----

ui <- 

  fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),

            fluidRow(
              
              column(3,
                     selectInput("select1", label = h4("Data Type"),
                                 choices = list("Type" = 1),
                                 selected = 1),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value1")),
              
              column(3,
                     selectInput("select2", label = h4("Data Unit"),
                                 choices = list("Unit" = 1),
                                 selected = 1),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value2")),                  

              
                column(3,
                       selectInput("select_market", label = h4("Market"),
                                   choices = mod.selection$market_name,
                                   verbatimTextOutput("value3")
                       )),
                
                column(3,
                       selectInput("select_submarket", label = h4("Sub Market"),
                                   choices = NULL),
                       verbatimTextOutput("value4")
                ),
              
              
              ),
            
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
              ),
              
              mainPanel(
              )
            )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach, which is to use `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()` to dynamically change widget:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(data.table)

market <- c("MarketA", "MarketB", "MarketC", "MarketA","MarketA")
submarket <- c("SubmarketX", "SubmarketY", "SubmarketZ", "SubmarketX","SubmarketX")
models <- c("modelA1", "modelB1", "modelC1", "modelA2","modelA3")
model_selector <- c("1","1","1","2","3")

# Create data table
mod.selection <- data.table(
  market_name = market,
  submarket_name = submarket,
  model_name=models,
  model_selector=model_selector
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$submarket_ui <- renderUI({
    req(input$select_market)
    
    submarket_choices <- unique(mod.selection[market_name == input$select_market, submarket_name])
    
    selectInput("select_submarket", label = h4("Submarket"),
                choices = submarket_choices, selected = submarket_choices[1])
  })
  
  output$model_ui <- renderUI({
    req(input$select_submarket)
    
    model_choices <- unique(mod.selection[market_name == input$select_market & submarket_name == input$select_submarket, model_selector])
    
    selectInput("select_model", label = h4("Model"),
                choices = model_choices, selected = model_choices[1])
  })
}

#Ui function----

ui <- 
  
  fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
            
            fluidRow(
              
              column(2,
                     selectInput("select1", label = h4("Data Type"),
                                 choices = list("Type" = 1),
                                 selected = 1),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value1")
              ),
              
              column(2,
                     selectInput("select2", label = h4("Data Unit"),
                                 choices = list("Unit" = 1),
                                 selected = 1),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value2")
              ),            
              
              column(2,
                     selectInput("select_market", label = h4("Market"),
                                 choices = unique(mod.selection$market_name),
                                 selected = unique(mod.selection$market_name)[1]),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value3")
              ),
              
              column(2,
                     uiOutput("submarket_ui"),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value4")
              ),
              column(2,
                     uiOutput("model_ui"),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value5")
              )
            ),
            
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
              ),
              
              mainPanel(
              )
            )
  )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

To ensure the widgets are on the same row, I changed the column width of each widget from 3 to 2 (they must add up to 12 or less).